# SAS creating a flag for each occurrence

Tags: sas

I currently have created this code below and it creates a flag(inputs 1 when follows condition and 0 when it doesn't) whenever there is 3 months of zeros, 9 months of non zeros and another 3 months of zeros. So it would be 0,0,0 for first three months and then 9 months of 20,10,40,50 etc and then another 3 months of zeros at the end of that 9 month period.

Is there a way to adapt the code below to wherever I get first three months of zeros, then find any ones that have consecutive non zeros, up to a period of nine months and it also has to end with three zeros after that nine month period. For example, for the 9 months of pay it would be 20,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 or 300,20,50,0,0,0,0,0,0 all the way up to 20,30,40,50,60,70,80,70,100. Any of these would count as a flag as long as they start and finish with 3 months of non pay.

I would also like these to have a flag of 1 every month this occurs and everything else that doesn't can stay as a zero. Example here:
if its becomes 0,0,0, first three months and then 20,40,50,0,0,0,0,0,0 I would like the data to input 0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 so it only flags 1 for the ones with consecutive non zeros starting from month 4. It has to be consecutive pay to have a flag, so if the 9 month period look like this 20,50,30,0,20,0,0,0,0 I only want the first 3 months to have a flag of 1 as the 0 breaks the chain before the 20 in month 5 of the 9 months pay

```
data want;
set have;
array pays(*) monthly_pay_201501--monthly_pay_202212;
array months(*) month1-month96;

* populate with first day of each month extracted from var name;
do _i = 1 to 96;
    months(_i) = input(scan(vname(pays(_i)), -1, '_'), yymmn6.);
end;

* ensure the dates are properly bounded;
format strt_dt end_dt date9.;
strt_dt = intnx('month', max(startdate, '1jan2015'd), 0);
end_dt = intnx('month', min(enddate, '31dec2022'd), 0);

* find the index of months array that matches the dates;
strt_indx = whichn(strt_dt, of months(*));
end_indx = whichn(end_dt, of months(*));

* validate the indices accurately reflect the true var;
strt_vname = vname(pays(strt_indx));
end_vname = vname(pays(end_indx));

flag=0;
if end_indx-strt_indx>=15 then do _i = strt_indx to end_indx-14 until(flag=1);
  if pays[_i]=0
    and pays[_i+1]=0
    and pays[_i+2]=0 
    and pays[_i+3]^=0 
    and pays[_i+4]^=0
    and pays[_i+5]^=0
    and pays[_i+6]^=0
    and pays[_i+7]^=0
    and pays[_i+8]^=0
    and pays[_i+9]^=0
    and pays[_i+10]^=0
    and pays[_i+11]^=0
    and pays[_i+12]=0
    and pays[_i+13]=0
    and pays[_i+14]=0
  then flag=1;
end; 

drop _: monthly_pay: month:;
run
```

The loop should first evaluate 201501 to 201603 then 201502 to 201604 for each Id. So each Id would be looped over multiple times until it reaches the last 15 month evaluation period. The code above does that but it only gives one flag. I need to output 96 months of flags each time the first three month start with a 0  and then gives a flag for each month of consecutive non zeros and then the last 3 month of the 15 month period should also be zeros. After evaluating the first 15 months it would move up one month for the same ID evaluating the next 15 month period. So first evaluation 201501 to 201603 and after that evaluation it would evaluate 201502 to 201604. if the 15 month period does not start or end with three months of zeros it would move to 201503 to 201605 and evaluate that 15 month period and give a flag of one every time the condition of consecutive values starting from month 4 in each 15 month evaluation period.

Comment: So you want inspect a 15 month interval and create a flag.  Which of the 15 months should get the flag? The first? The last? Something else?

Comment: Are there any gaps with missing dates?  What about missing pay values? Should those count as zero or something else? You did not show either your input data nor your desired result.   Do you really have the dates stored in the NAME of the variable instead of in a variable of its own?

Comment: The start date is 201501 up to 202212 and Every interval would be a 15 month period. So for each id i would start at 201501-201603 then 201502-201604 all the way up to the last 15 month period of 202110-202212. I would need to do this for each I'd. The output would be  flag of 1 or 0 for each month over a 96 month period

Comment: Which period does the flag represent?  The 15 months starting on that date? Or the 15 months ending on that date?

Comment: I want a flag that would go through every month so it the output would be flag_201501 flag_201502 up to flag_202212. All of these would be a 1 or a 0 for each id

Comment: Still not said which of the 15 dates should be flagged.  If at the starting of 01JAN2020 there are 15 months that meet your criteria should the flag for 01JAN2020 be a 1? Or should the flag for 01MAR2021 be a 1?